# How to set Leverage browser caching asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

How to set Leverage browser caching at ASP.net IIS 7.0
Setting an expiry date or a maximum age in the HTTP headers and for pictures in web.config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ASP.net, in the global.asax file, in the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute function call Response.Cache.SetExpires and Response.Cache.SetMaxAge methods.
For pictures or static content, in IIS 7 web.config use

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

replacing 7 days with desired duration.